# How to use a tochesBegan() method as an extension of a class?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, extension-methods

How can I add a touchesBegan() method to my class?

Here is my method:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches{

        let locationUser = touch.location(in: self)

        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class extension adding the method in it if your 
class is a subclass of UIView or UIWindow:

```
extension YourClass {
    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        for touch in touches{
            let locationUser = touch.location(in: self)
        }
        print("touchesBegan")
    }
}
```